# For a generalized irrational number c, is there another number d such that cd is rational.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If we have some irrational number c, is there a number d (real or not) such that cd=p/q (where p,q are co prime hence p/q is rational)? Its clear to me that d cannot be rational otherwise cd remains irrational

For the case that c=a+sqrt(b) (where a,b are rationals and b>0 and also not a square number so that c is irrational), then the only value of d such that cd=rational is d being the irrational conjugate of c which is a-sqrt(b).

But for a generalised irrational number c, i want to know if such a value of d exists. A simple soltion would be the multiplicitive inverse of c, but im not sure if there is a multiplicitive inverse for c.

Comment: This is too vague.  Let $d=\frac 1c$.  Is that an example of what you want? (since $c$ is irrational it can't be $0$).

Comment: Every nonzero real number has a real multiplicative inverse, which is irrational if and only if the original number is.

Comment: Sure. Take $d = p = 0$ and $q = 1$.

Comment: The background of this question, is that i want to show for a polynomial p(x) with rational coefficients, vietas theorem states that the product of its roots is equal to the constant term / leading coefficeint of the polynomial (which is a rational expression), and if c is a root to p(x) then so is d since then cdx(any other roots) = rational number, so its my bad for not defining d cant be 0

Comment: But if d = 1/c is always a soltion then, if p(c)=0 why is p(1/c) not equal to 0? Or is it

Comment: Keep in mind that many (well, most) irrationals are not roots of polynomials with rational coefficients.

Comment: Oh understandable, but for those that are, would i be correct by saying if p(c)=0 then p(1/c)=0?

Comment: YOU SAID, "For the case that c=a+sqrt(b) (where a,b are rationals and b>0 and also not a square number so that c is irrational), then the only value of d such that cd=rational is d being the irrational conjugate of c which is a-sqrt(b)."  You could also use d=k(a-sqrt(b)) where k is rational.

Comment: Then why isnt k(a-sqrt(b)) a root to a polynomial p(x) with rarional coefficients and a root a+sqrt(b), because my first approach was to use the fact that (a+sqrt(b))(e<sub>1)…(e<sub>n) being the product of the roots of p(x) degree n is equal to constant term/leading coefficient in this case e<sub>i for some i between 1<=i<=n should be d so that (a+sqrt(b))d is rational, its clear d could be a-sqrt(b) but as you said d could also be k(a-sqrt(b)) but the irrational root theorem says that only a-sqrt(b) is a root if a+sqrt(b) is of p(x)

Comment: For $d = 0$ we have $cd = 0 \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: "vietas theorem states that the product of its roots is equal to the **constant term / leading coefficeint of the polynomial**"  So the product is *one* **SPECIFIC** rational number.  Not just *any* rational number.  "and if c is a root to p(x) then so is d since then cdx(any other roots) = **rational number**" But it can't just be *any* rational number.  It *HAS* to be the leading coefficient.  There are an *INFINITE* number of rational numbers that *aren't* the leading coefficient.

Answer (score 0):

$cd = q$ if and only if $d = \frac qc$ (assuming $c \ne 0$ which as it is irrational you are assuming).

> For the case that c=a+sqrt(b) (where a,b are rationals and b>0 and also not a square number so that c is irrational), then the only value of d such that cd=rational is d being the irrational conjugate of c which is a-sqrt(b).

That's rather absurd.  $c=a+\sqrt{b}$ then *any* $d = \frac q{a+\sqrt b}$ for *any* rational $q$ will have the property that $cd$ is rational.  I think what your are trying to say is $d = a-\sqrt{b}$ is the only value so that $cd = a^2 - b$ which is one *specific* rational.

I think you are confusing *any* rational with a *specific* rational.

If $c$ is a set irrational and you have a particular rational $q$ (not equal to $0$) in mind, the there is *exactly* one irrational $d$ so that $cd = q$ and that is, of course, $d =\frac qc$.  (Note in your example $a-\sqrt b = \frac {a^2-b}{a+\sqrt b}$)

But if all you are asking is for a set irrational $c$ is there any $d$ so that $cd$ is rational.... well, there are an *infinite* number of them.  Any $d=\frac qc$ where $q$ is rational will do.

=====

Rereading (and rereading .... and rereading) I see you are trying to figure that if $p(x)$ is a polynomial with a constant term (let's) call it $k$ (and with the degree coefficient of $1$) that the product of the roots will be $k$.  In other words if the the roots are $c_1, c_2, ...., c_n$ then $\prod_{i=1}^n c_i =k$ and $k$ is rational.

You noticed that if $c=c_1$ is irrational that would seem to mean that we must have a $d$ so that $cd = k$ and thus there must be $d$ so that $cd$ is a rational number.

And the answer to that is, of course there is.  As $\prod_{i=1}^n c_i = k$ then $c_1\times \prod_{i=2}^n c_i = k$ and our $d = \prod_{i=2}^n c_i$.  But even if we didn't know anything about polynomials, we would know that if we wanted a $d$ so that $dc = k$ the answer to that is $d =\frac kc$.

But you made two mistakes.  You thought that if $c$ is a root and there is a $d$ so that $cd = k$ a rational number, that it was $cd$ is rational that was important.  It doesn't matter that $cd$ is *rational*.  There are an infinite number $d$ so that $cd$ is rational.  It is that $cd =k$ and $k$ alone that is important.  We can have $cd_0 = 7$ ($d_0 = \frac 7c$) or $cd_1 = 1.254$ (by letting $d_1 =\frac {1.254}c$) or any rational.  But to have $cd = k$ we *must* have $d =\frac kc$. That is the only number so that $cd=k$.

And you figured that if $c$ is a root and $d$ is the number so that $cd=k$ that that would mean $d$ is a root.  But no, as $k$ is the product of *all* roots $d$ has to be the product of all roots except $c$.  It isn't a root in itself unless the polynomial is of degree $2$ and there are only two roots (or a double root).

Comment: The statement "$cd = q$ if and only if $c = q/d$" does not work if $d=0, q=0$.

Comment: $d$ is given to be irrational.  So $d \ne 0$.

Comment: Oh, I got them swtched from the OPs notation..... I'll fix.

Comment: Yeh i was trying to prove the irrational root theorem, but made a huge mistake asuming that cd=any rational would do for the proof, it turns out it must be equal to a unique rational which is proved to be a^2 -b hence i used a different approach